# ReLU Variance in Practice Disagrees with Theory

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, relu

Let $X$ be a normally distributed random variable with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$. Theory tells us that $\mathbb{V}[\text{ReLU}(X)] = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{V}[X] = \frac{1}{2}$. Thus, we should have that $\mathbb{V}[\sqrt{2}\times\text{ReLU}(X)] = \mathbb{V}[X] = 1$.

However when I run this as an experiment with PyTorch this is not what I get. When I run the following program

```py
import torch
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

avars = []
rvars = []
relu = nn.ReLU()
for _ in range(1000):
    A = torch.normal(0, 1, size=(1, 10000))
    avars.append(torch.var(A).item())
    rvars.append(torch.var(np.sqrt(2) * relu(A)).item())

plt.xlabel('Input Variance')
plt.ylabel('Output Variance')
plt.title('Variance of ReLU Layer')

plt.scatter(avars, rvars)
print(np.mean(avars))
print(np.mean(rvars))
```

I get the following:

[image: Var]

My best guess at the amount that I am off is about 0.68162, which I don't recognize off the top of my head. Worse, this appears to be a constant between trials with a wide range of tensor sizes.

Where did I go wrong? What is this constant and where does it come from?

Comment: Theory tell us in this case that  $\mathbb{V}[\text{ReLU}(X)] \not = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{V}[X]$ since $\mathbb E[(\text{ReLU}(X))^2] =  \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ but  $\mathbb E[\text{ReLU}(X))] \not =0=\mathbb E[X]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z = xI$ and $I$ indicate if x is pos/neg.
$$
V[z] = E[(xI)^2] - E[xI]^2 = \frac{1}{2}E[x^2] - E[xI]^2,
$$
$$
E[xI] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty t e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}\,dt
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}[-e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}]_0^\infty=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
$$
so
$$
V[z] = \frac{1}{2}\cdot1 - \frac{1}{2\pi} \approx 0.34.
$$

Comment: Can you clarify why we compute the variance this way, instead of like so in this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/138035/319738? In this case $X$ is also symmetric around 0, so shouldn’t it hold?

Comment: @Variational: because the mean changes.  In your link it says $E[X^2]=\frac12 V[Y]$ but does not say $V[X]=\frac12 V[Y]$

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!